# How do I use the "since" parameter in the changes feed of a Cloudant DB?

Tags: ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant

I am working  with a Cloudant db and would like to use the `since` param in the changes feed using the `_changes` API call. Was looking for guidance one what would be valid entries for the `since` parameter. I know `0` and `now` are options but is there a way to get changes from a defined time period?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call the `_changes` API endpoint, you get a `last_seq` parameter in the response. This is a token that can be supplied to the `_changes` endpoint in a subsequent API call to get the next batch of changes.

For example, if you make an initial call to get changes in a database called `orders`:

```
GET /orders/_changes?limit=5
{
  "results": [
    {
      "seq": "1-g1AAAAB5eJzLYWBg",
      "id": "00002Sc12XI8HD0YIBJ92n9ozC0Z7TaO",
      "changes": [
        {
          "rev": "1-3ef45fdbb0a5245634dc31be69db35f7"
        }
      ]
    },
    ....
  ],
  "last_seq": "5-g1AAAAB5eJzLYWBg"
}
```

...you can then get subsequent changes by using the returned `last_seq` parameter:

```
GET /orders/_changes?limit=5&since=5-g1AAAAB5eJzLYWBg
{
  "results": [ ...],
  "last_seq": "10-g1AAAACbeJzLY"
}
```

However, it should be noted that programming against this changes feed is complicated for a number of reasons. For example, the changes are not strictly ordered in time sequence and may be duplicated between calls. Please read [this FAQ document](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-faq-using-changes-feed) for more details.